# Updating via an Access Query VBA SQL - Unable to update Choice Column

Tags: vba, ms-access, dynamics-365

I am trying to use Access with a VBA module to run code to update a table linked with Dynamics 365, the table has been updated with all other data from the source table but I cannot update one column that is a Choice data type. The records already exist and have no current value, they are a single selection choice.

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit
Sub test1()
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Dim strSQLUpdate As String
    
    ' Update the [Portfolio] field in the [Projects Table] table based on the value of the [Portfolio] field in the [Source Data] table.
    strSQLUpdate = "UPDATE [Projects Table] " & _
                    "INNER JOIN [Source Data] ON [Projects Table].[Sub Number] = [Source Data].[Sub Number] " & _
                    "SET [Projects Table].[Portfolio] = " & _
                    "IIf([Source Data].[Portfolio] = 'Lego Projects', '306170000', " & _
                    "IIf([Source Data].[Portfolio] = 'Car Projects', '306170001', " & _
                    "IIf([Source Data].[Portfolio] = 'Cooking Projects', '306170002', " & _
                    "IIf([Source Data].[Portfolio] = 'Arcade Projects', '306170003', " & _
                    "IIf([Source Data].[Portfolio] = 'Pool Projects', '306170004', " & _
                    "IIf([Source Data].[Portfolio] = 'Treehouse Projects', '306170005', " & _
                    "IIf([Source Data].[Portfolio] = 'Other Projects', '306170006', '')))))))"
                    "WHERE [SOURCE DATA].[Portfolio] IS NOT NULL;"
    db.Execute strSQLUpdate, dbFailOnError
    
    ' Clean up
    Set db = Nothing
End Sub
```

Currently I receive run-time error '3464' Data type mismatch in criteria expression. Edit: Appears to work now that I've added a WHERE clause to filter null values.

Comment: Another piece of advice, don't allow empty strings in table. I never do. Set to Null instead.

Comment: "Choice" is not a data type. It a design feature that can be applied to various type fields (text, number, date/time). I repeat advice to not set this in table design. Build comboboxes on form.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, I wanted to post the corrected code when I reproduced the error message. I will see if it is possible to change the table design.

Comment: Could have edited your original question but see you have now deleted it. Even with current design, should be able to update field with posted code if it is truly a TEXT type and not set as multi-value.

Comment: I assume [Sub Number] is same data type in both datasets because you say other fields are updated using these same datasets.

Comment: @June7 Yes this is correct. I think it is now working properly after filtering out null values. Thank you for your time trying to help me.